# Axios requests with express, node, ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am working on a site using Express.js, node.js, Axios, and ejs. I am making REST calls to a Oracle SQL REST services using Axios. I am having trouble working with Promises or Async/Await. I could use some guidance, if possible.

I have a repository layer to interface with the Oracle DB. For example:

**dataaccess.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.IsManufacturerCategory = function (categoryId) {
    axios.get(`DB ADDRESS ${categoryId}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.error('GET IsManufacturerCategory categoryId = ' + categoryId);
            console.error('Response = ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));

            return (response.data);
        })
        .catch(rej => {
            console.error('ERROR IsManufacturerCategory categoryId = ' + categoryId);
            console.error('ERR = \n' + rej.data);
            return (rej.data);
        });
}
```

Which is called in my middleware. When I call `var isManufacturerCat = exports.IsManufacturerCategory(categoryId);` it is undefined.  I am attempting to use the data retrieved from the Axios call to return a ejs view to my router, which I can provide if needed.

**category.js**

```
var isManufacturerCat = exports.IsManufacturerCategory(categoryId);
if (isManufacturerCat) {
    var models = dataaccess.GetCategorySubCategories(categoryId);
    return ("manufacturers", {
        data: {
            Canonical: cononical, 
            Category: category, 
            IsAManufacturerCategory: iAManufacturerCat, 
            Models: models
        }
    });
}
```

I am open to any advice in my project structure, usage of Promises, Async/Await, etc.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

After working with some of the answers given, I have made some progress but I am having issues with layers of async calls. I end up getting into a spot where I need to `await` a call, but I am in a function that I am not able/do not want to do so (i.e. my router).

**indexMiddleware.js**

```
exports.getRedirectURL = async function (fullOrigionalpath) {

    if (fullOrigionalpath.split('.').length == 1 || fullOrigionalpath.indexOf(".aspx") != -1) {
        if (fullOrigionalpath.indexOf(".aspx") != -1) { 
            //some string stuff to get url

        }
        else if (fullOrigionalpath.indexOf("/solutions/") != -1) {
            if (!fullOrigionalpath.match("/solutions/$")) {
                if (fullOrigionalpath.indexOf("/t-") != -1) {
                    //some stuff
                }
                else {
                    var solPart = fullOrigionalpath.split("/solutions/");
                    solPart = solPart.filter(function (e) { return e });

                    if (solPart.length > 0) {
                        var solParts = solPart[solPart.length - 1].split("/");
                        solParts = solParts.filter(function (e) { return e });
                        if (solParts.length == 1) {
                            waitForRespose = true;

                            const isASolutionCategory = await dataaccess.isASolutionCategory(solParts[0]); // returns void

                            if (isASolutionCategory != undefined && isASolutionCategory.length > 0 && isASolutionCategory[0].Count == 1) {
                                 // set redirecturl   
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            redirecturl = "/solutions/solutiontemplate";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (URL STUFF) {
            // finally if none of the above fit into url condition then verify current url with Category URL or product url into database and if that matches then redirect to proper internal URL
            if (fullOrigionalpath.lastIndexOf('/') == (fullOrigionalpath.length - 1)) {
                fullOrigionalpath = fullOrigionalpath.substring(0, fullOrigionalpath.lastIndexOf('/'));
            }

            waitForRespose = true;

            const originalURL = await exports.getOriginalUrl(fullOrigionalpath); //returns string
            redirecturl = originalURL;
            return redirecturl;
        }
    }

    if (!waitForRespose) {
        return redirecturl; 
    }
}

exports.getOriginalUrl = async function (friendlyUrl) {
    var originalUrl = '';
    var urlParts = friendlyUrl.split('/');
    urlParts = urlParts.filter(function (e) { return e });
    if (urlParts.length > 0) {
        var skuID = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

        const parts = await dataaccess.getFriendlyUrlParts(skuID); //returns void
        console.log("Inside GetOriginalUrl (index.js middleware) FriendlyUrlParts: " + parts);//undefined

        if (parts != undefined && parts != null && parts.length > 0) {
            //some stuff
        }
        else {
            // verify whether it's category URL then return the category local URL
            console.log('Getting CategoryLocalUrl');
            const categoryLocalUrl = await dataaccess.getCategoryLocalUrl(friendlyUrl); // returns void
            console.log('CategoryLocalUrl Gotten ' + JSON.stringify(categoryLocalUrl)); //undefined
            if (categoryLocalUrl != undefined && categoryLocalUrl.length > 0) {
                //set originalUrl
                return originalUrl;
            }

        }
    }
    else { return ''; }
}
```

**index.js router**

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
   //bunch of stuff
   index.getRedirectURL(url)
      .then(res => {
        req.url = res;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
      .finally(final => {
        next();
      });
}
```

I am getting `undefined` in my `console.log`s after the `await`s. I'm not really sure what I'm doing I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with dataaccess.js. Basically, you're exporting a function that's doing async work, but the function isn't async. Most people want to be able to utilize async/await, so rather than have `IsManufacturerCategory` accept a callback function, it would better to have the function return a promise. The easiest way to do that is to make the function an async function. Async functions return promises which are resolved/rejected more easily than by returning an explicit promise. Here's how that could be rewritten:

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.IsManufacturerCategory = async function (categoryId) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`DB ADDRESS ${categoryId}`);

    console.log('GET IsManufacturerCategory categoryId = ' + categoryId);
    console.log('Response = ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('ERROR IsManufacturerCategory categoryId = ' + categoryId);
    console.error('ERR = \n' + rej.data);

    throw err;
  }
}
```

Note that I'm using `console.error` only for errors. Because you wanted to log some error related details, I used a try/catch statement. If you didn't care about doing that, the function could be simplified to this:

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.IsManufacturerCategory = async function (categoryId) {
    const response = await axios.get(`DB ADDRESS ${categoryId}`);

    console.log('GET IsManufacturerCategory categoryId = ' + categoryId);
    console.log('Response = ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
}
```

This is because async functions automatically swallow errors and treat them as rejections - so the promise returned by `IsManufacturerCategory` would be rejected. Similarly, when an async function returns a value, the promise is resolved with the value returned.

Moving on to category.js... This looks strange because you're accessing `IsManufacturerCategory` from the exports of that module when I think you mean to access it from the import of the dataaccess module, right?

Inside this function, you should put any async work in an async function so that you can use await with function that return promises. Here's how it could be rewritten:

```
const dataaccess = require('dataccess.js');

async function validateManufacturerCat(categoryId) {
  const isManufacturerCat = await dataaccess.IsManufacturerCategory(categoryId);

  if (isManufacturerCat) {
    const models = await dataaccess.GetCategorySubCategories(categoryId);

    return ({
      manufacturers: {
        data: {
          Canonical: cononical, 
          Category: category, 
          IsAManufacturerCategory: iAManufacturerCat, 
          Models: models
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

validateManufacturerCat(categoryId)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

A couple notes:

1. I changed the return value in the `if` statement to be a single value. You should try to always return a single value when working with promises and async/await (since you can only resolve/return one value).
2. I see lots of functions starting with capital letters. There's a convention in JavaScript where functions with capital letters are constructor functions (meant to be invoked with the `new` keyword).

Comment: I've taken this into account and updated my code. As for the functions with capital letters, I inherited a codebase full of those functions, as well as callback hell. I am trying to convert it to something better than callbacks.

Comment: I hear you. It could be a codebase from before promises were even a thing and callback hell was more the norm - not everyone knew about the Async library. It's not needed as much these days, but it's still handy. Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: Where would I call the final promise that returns the result of all the layered promises? The information is needed in my router's `router.use` function, or in a route itself. For some reason, I feel like calling the promise in the router is not a good habit to get into. Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: One thing I was missing, and I had a lapse in absolute basic programming knowledge when I was changing my code, was a `return response.data` call inside the `exports.IsManufacturerCategory` function. I added this and the data was returned. I guess sometimes you just forget the basics.

Comment: Hi Josh, regarding the router, Express isn't currently designed to work with promises. Valeri Karpov discusses that here: http://thecodebarbarian.com/using-async-await-with-mocha-express-and-mongoose He uses a wrapper as a workaround, but went with a simple try/catch block. See this part of a tutorial I wrote: https://jsao.io/2018/04/creating-a-rest-api-handling-get-requests/ Note that I'm catching any exceptions raised in my logic and passing the error along to `next` which is what Express expects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. Note that you need a callback function to get the data when it is available from the promise

```
//client.js
const axios = require("axios")


    exports.IsManufacturerCategory = function (url, callback) { 
       axios.get(url)
         .then(response=>
            {
                 callback(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                callback( error);
            })
    };


    //app.js
   const client = require('./client');

    function process(data) {

        console.log(data)
    }    
     client.IsManufacturerCategory("http://localhost:3000/persons",process);
```

[documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: so would I remove the `var query = ` as well as use then and catch?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have layout your code as to how it should be. also you should return the data from the function

Comment: still getting an undefined value when i use `var IsAManufacturerCategory = dataaccess.IsManufacturerCategory(categoryId);`

Comment: I have updated the code. You need a callback function to get the data. The sample I did works as expected.

Comment: Okay so I changed my Axios call and the data is returning now, but the middleware is not waiting for the call to return before setting the `IsAManufacturerCategory` variable. Thats what was causing the undefined when i was testing. Is there something I can do to make it wait?  I appreciate the help